# How to Reference Existential Type Variables Inside Function Definition?

Tags: typed-racket

What's racket analogue of Haskell's `ScopedTypeVariables`? eg. in

```
(: f (All (k v l w)
          (-> (Listof k)
              (HashTable k v)
              (-> k v (Values l w))
              (HashTable l w))))
(define (f keys m g)
  (foldl (λ ([k : k] [m : (HashTable k v)]) ;; uh-oh!
           (let-values ([(l w) (g k (hash-ref m k))])
             (hash-set m l w)))
         #hash()
         keys))
```

`k` & `v` are out of scope! How can I get the existential variables bound in the `All` form in scope in the lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misdiagnosing the problem. `k`, `v`, `l` and `w` are in scope as type variables, but the types are incompatible (`k` can't unify with `l` and `v` can't unify with `w`). A different function that shows the type variables `l` and `w` working in the scope of the function-body, is this example:

```
(: f (All (k v l w)
       (-> (Listof k)
           (HashTable k v)
           (-> k v (Values l w))
           (HashTable l w))))
(define (f keys m g)
  (foldl (λ ([k : k] [acc : (HashTable l w)]) ; can refer to l and w
           (let-values ([(l w) (g k (hash-ref m k))])
             (hash-set acc l w)))
         (ann #hash() (HashTable l w)) ; can refer to l and w
         keys))
```